# Move a column to a new line

Tags: notepad++

I have a set of data that looks like this:

```
624 Commemorate your trip to 'Planet Hollywood' with merchandise and movie-themed souvenirs available inside the Planet Hollywood restaurant.
625 Dine on American roadhouse fare in an electric atmosphere filled with movie memorabilia at Downtown Disney West Side.
626 Dine, shop, and discover all that Disney has to offer outside of its four magical parks!
627 Enjoy dinner and a movie at this casual theatre restaurant located in the Downtown Disney Area.   628   Embellish your life with whimsical and enigmatic art, toys and jewelry.
```

I need the data to look like this:

```
624 
Commemorate your trip to 'Planet Hollywood' with merchandise and movie-themed souvenirs available inside the Planet Hollywood restaurant.
625 
Dine on American roadhouse fare in an electric atmosphere filled with movie memorabilia at Downtown Disney West Side.
626 
Dine, shop, and discover all that Disney has to offer outside of its four magical parks!
627 
Enjoy dinner and a movie at this casual theatre restaurant located in the Downtown Disney Area. 
628 
Embellish your life with whimsical and enigmatic art, toys and jewelry.
```

How can I accomplish this using notepad++?

Answer (score 1):

Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, then

Find what: `^(\d+)`
Replace with: `$1\n` <-- here add one or more `\n` depending of what you want as result.

To achieve the opposite, as asked in comment, just do that:

Find what: `^(\d+)\n` - You may use `\R` instead of `\n` if you don't know if there is `\n` or `\r` or `\r\n`
Replace with: `$1_` <-- here replace the `_` by a space, I use it for visibility.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the opposite of what I asked?

Comment: Do we need to be in the Reg Ex mode or normal mode?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if Notepad++ has that capability but it's a lot easier to do with Sublime Text.

1. Download and install sublime text if you don't have it installed
2. Copy and paste your text in the sublime text window
3. place you mouse on the first line where you want the column to break to the next line
4. Click and hold down the scroll wheel on your mouse and drag it vertically down to the last line.
5. At this point you should have a long vertical cursor that cuts across the lines of text
6. hit the enter key on your keyboard.

Hope that helps